# SVG Circle with sections, change automatically on interval with other div and if section is clicked show selected div.

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

I know the title is confusing but here is exactly what I mean:

I have a SVG circle that is divided in 5 sections just like the link preview

There is a div on the right side that changes its content based on the selected section of the circle, for example if the selected section is number 3

The text on the section turns white, the background of the path turns blue and the right div changes its content to the selected section.

My problem is, I need to make the same functionality BUT I Need it to be automatic, what this means is to be changing from section one--two--three--four five AND the content on the right div should change too with the same interval. I've tried Intervals with JavaScript, and it does work but only with one of the sections, either the circle or the div.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the **LIVE EXAMPLE**
[link to live example](http://tecnami.com/circletest/)

CODE:

HTML:

```
<div class="whatwedosection" style="position: relative;">
        <p class="title1">OUR PRODUCTS</p>
        <p class="title2">OUR APPS for Salesforce.com</p>
        <div class="line" style="margin-bottom: 30px;"></div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              <div class="col-md-3">

              <svg viewBox='0 0 110 110' style="margin-top: 10px;transform: rotate(18deg);">
                 <defs>                   <!-- Circular path with a radius of 40 -->

                   <path id="clockwise" d='M55,15 A40,40 0 0 1 55,95 A40,40 0 0 1 55,15'
                         transform="rotate(-54,55,55)"/>

                   <path id="counterclockwise" d="M35,93 a55,95 0 0,0 40,0" transform="rotate(-55,55,55)"></path>
                   <path id="counterclockwise2" d="M35,93 a55,95 0 0,0 40,0" transform="rotate(7,55,55)"></path>



                 </defs>


                 <a xlink:href="" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <path  class="frag logoa" id="f1" data-link="1" d='M55,55 L14.54915028125263,25.61073738537635 A50,50 0 0,1 70.45084971874736,7.447174185242318z' >
                    </path>
                    <text class="zone textosvg1" data-link="1" >
                       <textPath xlink:href="#clockwise" startOffset="10%" text-anchor="middle" >
                          one
                       </textPath>
                    </text>
                 </a>


                 <a xlink:href="" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <path class="frag logoa" id="f2" data-link="2"  d='M55,55 L70.45084971874736,7.447174185242318 A50,50 0 0,1 105,54.999999999999986z' ></path>
                    <text class="zone textosvg2" data-link="2" >
                       <textPath xlink:href="#clockwise" startOffset="30%" text-anchor="middle">
                          two
                       </textPath>
                    </text>
                 </a>



                 <a xlink:href="" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <path class="frag logoa" id="f3" data-link="3"  d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 70.45084971874738,102.55282581475768z'></path>
                    <text class="zone textosvg3" data-link="3"  >
                       <textPath xlink:href="#counterclockwise"  x="5" y="50"  startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
                          three
                       </textPath>
                    </text>

                 </a>


                 <a xlink:href="" style="text-decoration: none;" >
                    <path class="frag logoa" id="f4" data-link="4" d='M55,55 L70.45084971874738,102.55282581475768 A50,50 0 0,1 14.549150281252636,84.38926261462366z' ></path>
                    <text class="zone textosvg4" data-link="4" >
                       <textPath xlink:href="#counterclockwise2"  x="5" y="50"  startOffset="30%" text-anchor="middle">
                         four
                       </textPath>
                    </text>
                 </a>
                 <a xlink:href=""  style="text-decoration: none;" >
                    <path class="frag logoa" id="f5" data-link="5" d='M55,55 L14.549150281252636,84.38926261462366 A50,50 0 0,1 14.54915028125263,25.61073738537635z' ></path>
                    <text class="zone textosvg5" data-link="5" >
                       <textPath xlink:href="#clockwise"  startOffset="90%" text-anchor="middle">
                         five
                       </textPath>
                    </text>
                 </a>
                 <circle class="cente" cx='55' cy='55' r='35' ></circle>
                 <circle class="minicirculo" cx='55' cy='55' r='15' ></circle>
              </svg>

            </div>
             <div class="col-md-5" >
                <div class="casa monitores" data-link="1">
                    <div class="fixed">
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="sideruedai">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-item">
                    <p class="title22" style="margin-top: 15px;" >first</p>
                    <p class="textsliderp" style="margin-top: -20px;">first</p>
                    <p class="textoinfo">
                   first
                    </p>
                   <button class="botonavandel hvr-grow">Read More</button></div>
                </div>

                <div class="casa monitores" data-link="2">
                    <div class="fixed">
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="sideruedai">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-item">
                    <p class="title22" style="margin-top: 15px;" >Second</p>
                    <p class="textsliderp" style="margin-top: -20px;">Second</p>
                    <p class="textoinfo">
                    second
                    </p>
                   <button class="botonavandel hvr-grow">Read More</button></div>
                </div>

                <div class="casa monitores" data-link="3">
                    <div class="fixed">
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="sideruedai">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-item">
                    <p class="title22" style="margin-top: 15px;" >third</p>
                    <p class="textsliderp" style="margin-top: -20px;">third</p>
                    <p class="textoinfo">
                    third
                    </p>
                   <button class="botonavandel hvr-grow">Read More</button></div>
                </div>

                <div class="casa monitores" data-link="4">
                    <div class="fixed">
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="sideruedai">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-item">
                    <p class="title22" style="margin-top: 15px;" >four</p>
                    <p class="textsliderp" style="margin-top: -20px;">four</p>
                    <p class="textoinfo">
                    four
                   <button class="botonavandel hvr-grow">Read More</button></div>
                </div>

                <div class="casa monitores" data-link="5">
                    <div class="fixed">
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="sideruedai">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-item">
                    <p class="title22" style="margin-top: 15px;" >fifth</p>
                    <p class="textsliderp" style="margin-top: -20px;">fifth</p>
                    <p class="textoinfo">
                    fifth.
                    </p>
                   <button class="botonavandel hvr-grow">Read More</button></div>
                </div>




             <div class="col-md-2" >

            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>


    </div>
```

css:

```
.textosvg1{
  fill:gray;
  font-size: 6px;
}
.textosvg2{
  fill:gray;
  font-size: 6px;
}
.textosvg3{
  fill:gray;
  font-size: 6px;
}
.textosvg4{
  fill:gray;
  font-size: 6px;
}
.textosvg5{
  fill:gray;
  font-size: 6px;
}
.textosvg6{
  fill:gray;
  font-size: 6px;
}

.slidertext{
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#1456a0;
  text-align: left;s
}
.frag {
  fill: white;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: .5;
  transition: fill 0.3s ;
}
text a {
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: middle; /* doesn't work in IE */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.monitores:not(:nth-child(1))').hide();
 $('.textosvg1').css({ fill: 'white' });
 $('#f1').css({ fill: '#1456a0' });

    $('.zone').click(
        function() {
            $('.monitores').hide();
            $('.monitores[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn();

        });


    $('.textosvg1').click(function() {
        $('.textosvg1').css({ fill: 'white' });
        $('#f1').css({ fill: '#1456a0' });

        $('.textosvg2').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f2').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg3').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f3').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg4').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f4').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg5').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f5').css({ fill: 'white' });


    });
    $('.textosvg2').click(function() {
        $('.textosvg2').css({ fill: 'white' });
        $('#f2').css({ fill: '#1456a0' });

        $('.textosvg1').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f1').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg3').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f3').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg4').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f4').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg5').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f5').css({ fill: 'white' });

    });

     $('.textosvg3').click(function() {
        $('.textosvg3').css({ fill: 'white' });
        $('#f3').css({ fill: '#1456a0' });

        $('.textosvg1').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f1').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg2').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f2').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg4').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f4').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg5').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f5').css({ fill: 'white' });

    });
     $('.textosvg4').click(function() {
        $('.textosvg4').css({ fill: 'white' });
        $('#f4').css({ fill: '#1456a0' });

        $('.textosvg1').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f1').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg2').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f2').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg3').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f3').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg5').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f5').css({ fill: 'white' });

    });
    $('.textosvg5').click(function() {
        $('.textosvg5').css({ fill: 'white' });
        $('#f5').css({ fill: '#1456a0' });

        $('.textosvg1').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f1').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg2').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f2').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg3').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f3').css({ fill: 'white' });

        $('.textosvg4').css({ fill: 'gray' });
        $('#f4').css({ fill: 'white' });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution my self, created different functions in Jquery in case you want to check it out!

The thing was to have a variable to check if during the interval something is clicked stop it then  empty every color.

```
var cont = 1;
var clicked = false;
var intervalo;


function spinner(c){
     intervalo = setInterval( function (){
            if (cont==5) {
                $('.textosvg' + cont).css({ fill: 'gray' });
                $('#f' + cont).css({ fill: 'white' });
                cont = 0;
                $('.textosvg' + cont).css({ fill: 'white' });
                $('#f' + cont).css({ fill: '#1456a0' });
            }
         $('.textosvg' + cont).css({ fill: 'gray' });
         $('#f' + cont).css({ fill: 'white' });
        cont++; 
         $('.textosvg' + cont).css({ fill: 'white' });
         $('#f' + cont).css({ fill: '#1456a0' });
        var first = $(".monitores:first-of-type").remove();
        $(".monitores").parent().append(first);


    }, 2300); 


}

spinner(cont);

$(document).on("click","path,text",function() {
     clicked = true;
     var element =  $('.monitores[data-link=' + $(this).attr('data-link') + ']').remove();
     $(".monitores").parent().prepend(element);
       if (clicked == true) {
        clearInterval(intervalo);
        vaciarCircle();
        var pat =  ('.textosvg' + $(this).attr('data-link') + '');
        var txt =  ('#f' + $(this).attr('data-link') + '');
        $(pat).css({ fill: 'white' });
        $(txt).css({ fill: '#1456a0' });
    }

});

function vaciarCircle(){
    for (var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
            $('.textosvg' + i).css({ fill: 'gray' });
            $('#f' + i).css({ fill: 'white' });
        }
}
```